# ng-show don't hide element, when it's falsy

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using code bellow (Angular + Material). Everything is OK, but when the expression of `ng-show` is changed to **false**, the element is still visible.

When you click on the `md-button` in the `md-toolbar`, console will log the changed value (false), but the element `md-content` is still visible.

Can you help me to solve this problem please? If any more details needed, I can put it here.

**UPDATE:** when I will move the button to the template `templates/sidebar/template.html` , it works fine.

**SOLVED:** I used the `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` in my controller and everything works!

**HTML:**

```
<body layout="column">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <md-button ng-controller="sidebar" ng-click="sidebarClose()" class="md-icon-button"><!-- hide-gt-md -->
                <md-icon aria-label="Menu" md-svg-icon="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/68133/menu.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <h1><img src="img/yt.png" class="img-rounded" /> My project</h1>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <section layout="row" id="content">
        <md-content ng-controller="sidebar" ng-show="sidebarOpened" layout-padding md-scroll-y ng-include="'templates/sidebar/template.html'" style="width:304px;">        
        </md-content>

        <md-content ng-controller="homepage" flex layout-padding md-scroll-y ng-include="'templates/home/template.html'">
        </md-content>
    </section> 
</body>
```

**Sidebar controller**

```
app.controller("sidebar", function($scope, $mdSidenav) {

    $scope.sidebarOpened = true;

    $scope.sidebarOpen = function() {
        $scope.sidebarOpened = true;  
        console.log($scope.sidebarOpened);
    };

    $scope.sidebarClose = function() {
        $scope.sidebarOpened = false;
        console.log($scope.sidebarOpened);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element with `ng-show="sidebarOpened"` is outside of the element with `ng-controller="sidebar"` containing the button. So they don't use the same controller instance, nor the same scope, and the value written in the controller is thus not the one read by `ng-show`.

The body should be handled by a main controller, containing the flag and the method to hide/show the sidebar. The button should not be inside a sidebar controller.

Comment: HA! Thank you man, i used $rootScope instead of $scope in my controller and it's works !!!!

Comment: Instead of using $rootScope keep the button in the main controller and use $scope. Populating $rootScope object is not a good practice